# Email for xampp: Having parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@'

Tags: php, email, xampp, phpmailer

**Error Received:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\FYP_v4\mailSMTP.php on line 11

I am using PHPmailer from Github. I was supposed to receive a email after running **mailSTMP.php** to authorize the username, but ended up receiving the error mentioned above instead. Please advise and assist. Thank you!

From **mailSTMP.php**,

```
//require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'username@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->From = 'username@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mohammad Masoudian';
$mail->AddAddress('xxxxxxx@mail.com');
$mail->AddReplyTo('xxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'Information');

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "PHPMailer Test Subject via Sendmail, basic";
$mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
$mail->Body = "Hello";

$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
if (!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

From **php.ini**,

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path=".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\xampp\htdocs\FYP_v4"
;
; PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear"
; http://php.net/include-path
```

From **sendmail.ini**,

```
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=587

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

;default_domain=mydomain.com

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

;debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username= username@gmail.com
auth_password= password

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

pop3_server= smtp.gmail.com
pop3_username= username@gmail.com
pop3_password= password


; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender= username@gmail.com

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=
```

Comment: I can't see a syntax error in line 11 of mailSTMP.php. Is it really the code that brings up that error?

Comment: It's not something silly like pasting code that's had quotes turned into curly ones?

Comment: @hellcode seems to be whenever i tried running mailSTMP.php for a test. Not sure what went wrong though..

Comment: @Synchro sorry, i dont really get what did you mean by that..

Comment: Just thought it could be something like you'd pasted `$mail->Username = ‘username@gmail.com’;` instead of `$mail->Username = 'username@gmail.com';` (note the difference in quotes). Whatever it is, it's got to be pretty basic to cause a simple sytax error.

Comment: Hi @Synchro, you were right, I did not format the quotation marks properly. Also, I did not insert the other relevant PHP files in the same folder as mailSTMP. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you write about the solution in the answer box provided? This is preferable to editing the word solved into the question.